# Apache/httpd didn't load PHP file after a while

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, webserver

So I just installed apache/httpd on my CentOS 7, the problem is, when apache starts, it executes the php code **but** after a while it doesn't anymore

For example i tried to restart httpd

`systemctl restart httpd`

And then i open **http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/info.php**
It executes normally, but after a while, i tried to opened it again... **info.php** seems to no longer executed and just loading page appear and nothing displayed..

Im using **PHP 5.4.16** and **CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009**

Comment: The Apache error logs (likely somewhere under /var/log) should contain details about whatever your issue is. Also note that PHP 5.4 is pretty ancient and should not be used on a production machine.

Comment: Did you check some other urls http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/index.php etc

Comment: Are the requests queued up? If you look at the network tab is it a pending request or do you get back a 500 or 200?

Comment: Should I update my php version?

Comment: It seems just a loading page (i guess it try to load info.php), but it took a long time and ended up with connection error (my internet run normaly so its not my connection problem)